# How can i transfer data from python to opc da server?

Tags: python, client-server, opc, opc-da

I have written a code in PYTHON. I want to transfer the respective outputs to OPC DA server so that clients can access it from the explorer. Can I create an empty configured aliases where I can fill it with my values and then display it or any similar logical easy solution ? the only way I figured out was to transfer the output data to a simulated item but that is not really a solution since I only want to show my data..

Comment: have you tried http://openopc.sourceforge.net/  or http://pyopc.sourceforge.net/?

Comment: To be honest, I am a beginner in the opc da so I am still finding for the solution of my problems. Is it possible that you guide me/ send me a helpful link/documentation,etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer values with [MODBUS or OPC](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/DataAcquisition). You can do this with [OpenOPC](http://openopc.sourceforge.net/) or [PyOPC](https://pypi.org/project/PyOPC/) but you may want to use the newer OPC-UA standard. There is a well-developed [Python package for OPC-UA](https://python-opcua.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Here is example code with OpenOPC if you do need to use the older DA standard.

```py
# #######################################
# OPC write
# #######################################
try:
    # OPC connection
    import OpenOPC
    opc=OpenOPC.client()
    b=opc.connect('Kepware.KEPServerEX.V5')
    #opc.connect('Kepware.KEPServerEX.V5','localhost')

    Load1_avg  = opcm[0][0]
    Load2_avg  = opcm[0][1]

    opc.write( ('Channel2.Device1.T_12_Load_AVG',Load1_avg) )
    opc.write( ('Channel2.Device1.T_21_Load_AVG',Load2_avg) )

    opc.close()
except:
    print 'OPC communication failed'
    pass
```

I've used this successfully with a Kepware server on several applications.

Answer (score 0):

Code for manipulation values through OPC DA, similar to the answer from @john-hedengren , but with the use of [QuickOPC](https://www.opclabs.com/products/quickopc/languages-and-tools/python) library:

```python
import opclabs_quickopc
from OpcLabs.EasyOpc.DataAccess import *
from OpcLabs.EasyOpc.OperationModel import *

client = EasyDAClient()

try:
    IEasyDAClientExtension.WriteItemValue(client, '', 'Kepware.KEPServerEX.V5', 'Channel2.Device1.T_12_Load_AVG', Load1_avg)
    IEasyDAClientExtension.WriteItemValue(client, '', 'Kepware.KEPServerEX.V5', 'Channel2.Device1.T_21_Load_AVG', Load2_avg)
except OpcException as opcException:
    print('*** Failure: ' + opcException.GetBaseException().Message, sep='')
    exit()
```

OPC UA (Unified Architecture) would require some changes, but the code would be similar in principle.